# How do you write a function that returns a node which value corresponds to a value stored in a variable?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I stumbled across this question in an old textbook I bought ages ago, whilst strictly speaking it is not too difficult, I could not find a post here that simply answered this one question. As such I thought "Hey perhaps someone starting out might be confused about this", and so I put together the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Structures
struct charNode {
    char Node;
    charNode *next;
};

// Functions
charNode* getCharNode(char c) {
    return ; //<----- Return Node Here 
}
```

Comment: You probably just need to do a "linked list". Search for it as there are a lot tutorials.

Comment: The books itself should probably contain a section on linked lists and how to work with them, otherwise this exercise would be kind of pointless.

Comment: Your question is missing a question. I strongly doubt that "Hey, here is a random code snippet without any explanation what so ever" is going to help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

What this needs is to be put in a `class` or else you must have a global variable that points to the *head* of that singly linked list.

An example `class` could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class singly_linked_list {
    struct charNode {
        char Node;
        charNode *next;
    };

public:
    // find the charNode with the value `c`:
    charNode* getCharNode(char c) {
        for(charNode* curr = head; curr != nullptr; curr = curr->next) {
            if(curr->Node == c) return curr;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    // add member functions to add/remove charNode's from the list etc
    // and implement one of "the rule of 3" or "the rule of 5"

private:
    charNode* head = nullptr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `getCharNode()` function like in following code. I used this function for an example of creating singly linked list of chars. Also created extra function `print_list()` which outputs linked list to console.

Notice that I did only allocation of nodes (`new` operator), and didn't do deallocation (`delete`), I left this task for you to do, if you care about memory leaks.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/9hPnz199W)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Structures
struct charNode {
    charNode(char value, charNode * _next = nullptr)
        : Node(value), next(_next) {}
    char Node;
    charNode *next;
};

// Functions
charNode* getCharNode(char c, charNode * next = nullptr) {
    return new charNode(c, next);
}

void print_list(charNode const * node) {
    if (!node)
        return;
    std::cout << node->Node << " ";
    print_list(node->next);
}

int main() {
    charNode * list = getCharNode('a',
        getCharNode('b', getCharNode('c')));
    print_list(list);
}
```

Output:

```
a b c
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo In second paragraph of my answer I noted that this program has intentional leak to leave deallocation task as a homework, because it was out of scope of original question.

Comment: I noticed so I removed that comment :-) But "_if you care about memory leaks_" is probably not a good thing to say to someone new to C++.

Comment: Funny how we interpreted `getCharNode` differently. I interpreted it as _search for_ and you as _create_.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Usually all who're new to C++ don't care about memory leaks at all. Even teachers in schoold who give task don't demand to do deallocation, because they usually care about central algorithm of requested task, and don't care about supplementary C++ stuff, like having no leaks. Of course in production code it is of great importance to have not a single leak.

Comment: @TedLyngmo In original question `getCharNode()` was a global function, not method. So I thought the only interpretation of `getCharNode()` which has only `char` input is to return newly created node. Unless there was a global variable holding a list, only then it could search in something. Of course if to make this function a method, or to give extra `charNode *` param then it can be used to search.

Comment: "_teachers in schoold who give task don't demand to do deallocation_" - That sounds terrible. When reaching the stage when manual memory management is taught (which should be pretty far into the course), freeing the allocated resources should be one of the key points.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Terrible, but possible. I myself remember that several teachers in my school and university never cared about side details, unrelated to central meaning of algorithm itself. In other words they cared only about mathematical part of a code, for example that the code ouputs correct numbers. Of course if a lesson is strictly about memory management then it always contains warnings about deallocation and in more advanced cases about using RAII for safe deallocation. Tasks at school are very like online contest problems, and many online contest sites don't sanitize deallocation at all.